# About the gaps between consecutive primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If my question is inappropriate, non-uniform or ill-shaped; please comment (or edit maybe).

Let $t(n)$ be the nth triangle number, so $t(n) = {(n)(n+1) \over 2}$.

And let $p(n)$ be the nth prime number.

I want to show that $t(n) > p(n)$ for all $n>2$. I tried this:

Let $t(n) > p(n)$ and $p(n+1) > t(n+1)$. If I can get a contradiction, I'm done.

With this I have $p(n+1) - p(n) > t(n+1) - t(n) = n+1$.

I tried to show the last part and couldn't. I checked with computer and if my code is correct, this last part is probably correct.

Then, I looked at Wikipedia's Prime Gap article and get suspicious.

Thanks any help for proving last part and checking first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) that $p_n \lt n (\ln n + \ln \ln n)$ for $n \ge 6$, 
and also $(\ln n + \ln \ln n) \le (n+1)/2$ for $n \ge 6$. So you have the result for $n \ge 6$ and you can check the rest by hand.

The result I quote is a bit complicated to obtain, though.

Comment: Thanks - Can you give a reference for $ (ln n + ln ln n) \leq (n+1)/2$ part? Also is $p(n+1) - p(n) > n+1$ part true?

Comment: To see this you could use that $\ln \ln n \le \ln n$ and then show that $2 \ln n \le (n+1)/2$. to do the latter you could take derivatives at both sides, having $2/n$ at the right and $1/2$ at the left, so you have the inequality for the derivative and then check it is true  for $n=7$ so also for all larger values. (And for 6 check manually the original.)

Comment: And yes the difference between n+1 th and nth  prime can never be n+1; this follow from result on prime gaps, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap and upper bounds, the result of Hoheisl for example (in combination with the bounds on p_n I just recalled). I do not have a reference that gives the resumt for all n handy. Also there should be simpler arguments.

Comment: I looked Prime gap article but couldn't find any result about $p(n+1) - p(n) < n + 1 $. I really thank if you can prove this.

Comment: It states there that $g_n \lt p_n^{\theta}$ for some $\theta < 1$  for large $n$ and so with the bound above $g_n \lt (2 n  \ln n)^{\theta}$. Eventually this is less than $n$. [This is not a good  argument but somehow clumsy for the purpose, but this is what I meant.]

Answer (score 1):

Rosser and Schoenfeld (1962), page 69, Theorem 3, Formula (3.11), 
$$   \mbox{for} \; \;  n \geq 20, \; \; \; \; p(n) < n (\log n + \log \log n - \frac{1}{2})    $$

Here we go, as corollary, (3.13)
$$   \mbox{for} \; \;  n \geq 6, \; \; \; \; p(n) < n (\log n + \log \log n )    $$

This is quite a good bound, as (3.12)
$$   \mbox{for} \; \;  n \geq 1, \; \; \; \; p(n) > n \log n     $$

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to show that

$$\pi(n(n+1)/2)\ge n$$

where $\pi(x)$ is the usual prime-counting function.  Since $\pi(x)$ is nondecreasing, it suffices to let $u=n^2/2$, find where

$$\pi(x)\gt\sqrt{2x}$$

for all $x\ge u$, and then check any smaller cases that might remain.  There ought to be some fairly simple proof that finds a fairly small $u$ past which the desired inequality holds. (The Prime Number Theorem, of course, says that $\pi(x)\approx x/\log x$ for large $x$, which is quite a bit larger than $\sqrt{2x}$.  Since there's so much room to spare, there should be a proof that doesn't rely on PNT.)